# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=0$ on $[0,\pi],$ where $f_n(x)=\cos^n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Prove that $\lim _{n\to\infty} f_n=0$ on $[0,\pi],$ where $f_n(x)=\cos^n(x)$

It's not difficult to see that when $x\in(0,\pi)$, we can take some large $N$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $n\ge N$ would imply that $|\cos^n(x)|<\sqrt\frac{\epsilon}{\pi}$, which would give us $\int_0^\pi |\cos^n(x)-0|^2 dx<\epsilon$.

But it puzzles me that, when $x=0$ or $x=\pi$,$f_n(x)=1$, which implies that $\int_0^\pi |f_n-0|^2 dx=\pi.$ Did I miss something when revealing the definition of *mean convergence*? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** for each $r\in(0,\pi)$:
$$x\in [r,\pi - r]\implies |\cos^n x|\le \cos^n r $$ so
$$
\int_0^1 |\cos^n x| dx \le (\pi - 2r)\cos^n r + \int_0^r  |\cos^n x| dx 
+ \int_{\pi - r}^\pi  |\cos^n x| dx 
\le \pi \cos^n r + 2r
$$
because $|\cos(.)|\le 1$.